# Making a preview in ReactJs using viewport width (vw) for placing elements in minor scale

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, viewport-units

I'm building a component in ReactJs that shows some text over a image in a page. This text is configured in a configuration manager app that is created with ReactJs too.

I am using vw (viewport width) as units, beacuse this component needs to be responsive. Using those units the size text is always fitted right. And if I resize the windows the text is in the same place.

My problem is the configuration manager where I configure the text that is going to appear, because I am making a preview of this component inside of modal window.

I need to locate correctly and exactly where the text will appear like if it were the orignal render. It needs to be like a minature of the real component.
I am using vw too, but it doesn't work. It appears in another site of the container and also when I resize the window the text moves too. 
I tried to use vmin units, but they did not work too.

I need the container to take the reference as if it were the browser window so that the viewport width units use the same measurements like a preview.

Or if you have any other idea to do this.

This is a reduced part of the code in ReactJS. Also the state is charged with test data for understanding the problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/main.scss';


class PreviewEditor extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: {
                text: '',
                fontSize: 2,
                position: {
                    vertical: {
                        key: 'top',
                        value: 20
                    },
                    horizontal: {
                        key: 'right',
                        value: 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        let object = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='container-body'>
                    <div>
                        <div className="container-preview">
                            <img src={object.url}></img>
                            <div className="conteiner-text" style={{
                                [this.state.text.position.vertical.key]: this.state.text.position.vertical.value + "vw",
                                [this.state.text.position.horizontal.key]: this.state.text.position.horizontal.value + "vw",
                                fontSize: this.state.text.fontSize + "vw",
                            }}>
                                <label>{this.state.text.text}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        ............ TODO
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default PreviewEditor
```

And this the css part

```
.container-preview {
  background-color: #2dc5c5;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.container-preview > img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.conteiner-text{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vw` stands for `viewport width`, it aims at always setting size relative to the current viewport, no matter the container. If you just want size relative to container width you should rather user percentage sizes. 
So, in your case, you could set each container width differently (using vw for the actual container and pixels for the preview, for example) and all their content sizes in percentage to always have the same ratio at different scales.